# Choosing Birth Day from ui-datepicker-calendar with selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to do a automated filling form for this web https://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/appointment_showForm.do?locationCode=pris&realmId=362&categoryId=2065 and i'm having troubles with Birth Date, i tried some commands but none of them are working.

Comment: can you show us what have you already tried? What are the errors etc.

Comment: date = driver.find_element_by_xpath(']path ')
select_date = Select(date)
select_date.select_by_visible_text(21) # 21 is the day examble
the error i get is: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <table>



the only way i can get it working is this 
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click() # i have to inspect element on the number of the date and copy the xpath.... i'm not a pro so this is the only solution i found

Answer (score 0):

could you give us some extra information ? since we are not sure what you applying to deal with it although this could help you.

```
 private WebElementFacade focusDayToBeClicked(LocalDate date) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10);
    
    Selector by = By.cssSelector("[data-handler="selectDay"]")
    wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));

    return findAll(by).stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getText().trim().equals(String.valueOf(date.getDayOfMonth()))).findFirst();
  }
  
  public void clickOnDay(LocalDate date){
  
  focusDayToBeClicked(date).click()
  
  }
```

To deal with the year and month you could use the Select class and based on the text or value choose the expected value.
[select class documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_select_elements/)